# ValueError with 'ciphers' when importing paramiko

Tags: python, windows, paramiko, python-3.3

I want to install paramiko on win 7 32bit ,the python is 3.3 .
I can compile it，but get follow errors:

```
Installed c:\python33\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.8.0-py3.3.egg
Processing dependencies for paramiko==1.8.0
Searching for pycrypto==2.6
Best match: pycrypto 2.6
Adding pycrypto 2.6 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\python33\lib\site-packages
Finished processing dependencies for paramiko==1.8.0

C:\Users\MC\Downloads\paramiko-paramiko-v1.8.0-9-g786920a>python
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:55:48) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".\paramiko\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from .transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File ".\paramiko\transport.py", line 68, in <module>
    class SecurityOptions (object):
ValueError: 'ciphers' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable
>>>
```

Comment: But Paramiko does not yet run on Python 3: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/16, or are you playing with some development branch?

Answer (score 0):

Paramiko does not run on Python 3.  Yet.  I'm working on a development branch (https://github.com/dorianpula/paramiko/tree/python3-support) to add support for Python 3, and I'm working on fixing this particular issue.